# Android studio build script error,unsupported gradle DSL method found : android()!

Tags: android-studio

I upgraded the Android Studio to AS 0.6 then imported the project developed in AS 0.3

I am getting errors like:

```
Build script error,unsupported Gradle DSL method found : android()'!,

Possible causes could be:  

 - you are using Gradle version where the method is absent 
    ("open_gradle_settings">Fix Gradle settings</a>)

 - you didn't apply Gradle plugin which provides the method 
    (<a href="apply_gradle_plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a>)

or there is a mistake in a build script (<a href="goto_source">Goto source</a>)
```

I changed my dependencies path in `build.gradle` to:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 14
}
```

What might the problem?

Is there any guide which tells how to upgrade the project?

Answer (score 2):

Actually it stated in the error message. So just add

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

between `dependencies` section and `android` section

Answer (score -1):

Think of “Gradle DSL method” as a Java method. So in Gradle, methods can be distinguished by either {} or “.”. So

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

is the same as

```
dependencies.compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

where both “dependencies” and “compile” are methods.

So you are including a method somewhere in your build.gradle file that is not supported by your program. For example, make your dependencies this:

```
dependencies {
    nothing 'this.does.nothing.build:gradle:0.7.+'
}
```

Which is the same as writing:

```
dependencies.nothing 'this.does.nothing.build:gradle:0.7.+'
```

And you will see an error saying “unsupported Gradle DSL method found: ‘nothing()’!” 
Obviously "nothing" is not a real method. I just made it up.

So one of your "android" methods is wrong.