# Android Studio first project error

Tags: android, android-studio

I've successfully installed Android Studio (0.6.1) on OS X (10.9.3). I can't get my first Hello World! project... Please help me solve this issue

This is the error I got:

> Error:(19, 0) Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found:
>   'android()'!
>
> Possible causes could be:
>     - you are using Gradle version where the method is absent (Fix Gradle settings)
>     - you didn't apply Gradle plugin which provides the method (Apply Gradle plugin)
>     - or there is a mistake in a build script (Goto source)

**Update: (code, error message)**

Script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {}
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1'
    defaultConfig {}
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
}
```

Error message:

> Error:(8, 0) Plugin with id 'android' not found.

Comment: Write your build.gradle file.

Comment: Take a look to my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163573/android-studio-build-script-error-unsupported-gradle-dsl-method-found-android/24167467#24167467

Comment: @EugenMartynov it still does not work...

Comment: Should I just reinstall?

Comment: Share with build.gradle. It is not problem with Android Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify it to next:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  } 
}

apply plugin: 'android' 

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
} 

android {
  compileSdkVersion 19
  buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
  defaultConfig {}
  productFlavors {
  } 
}

dependencies { }
```

Comment: Is it okay if I just copy and past the whole code (replace the original)

Comment: Sure, It is actually your code with small modifications

Comment: Now I get this error: `Error:(11, 0) Plugin with id 'android' not found.` and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153739/android-studio-plugin-with-id-android-library-not-found) does not solve the problem..

Comment: what is gradle version for you `gradle -v`

Comment: I am not sure what gradle version is... If I type that into the terminal I get this: `bash: gradle: command not found`

Comment: When you pasted new code did you synchronize build.gradle in Android Studio?

Comment: I have restarted AS and this is the error I got again: `Error:(11, 0) Plugin with id 'android' not found.` On top of the command lines (codes) it says: "Gradle sync failed. Basic functionality..." I must be missing an important step but I am not sure where... Probably really basic.

Comment: Can you check gradle location on your AS options

Comment: Sorry I am not sure how I do that... But I am sure that I am not using gradle version 1.1 (I have updated my question)

Comment: How did you install gradle? Brew or mac ports?

Comment: I did not install gradle when I installed AS. I only just installed it  using Brew and I am getting this error now: `Error:(8, 0) Plugin with id 'android' not found.`

Comment: You need to specify "brew" gradle as main gradle in Android Studio settings

Comment: Could you tell me how to do that please on [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298896/android-studio-error-8-0-plugin-with-id-android-not-found)?